# HTML-list -> choose an item, pass parameters

Tags: html, list, parameters

I'm building a  list from  a JSON file with jQuery. This list is nested with 2 dimensions.

For example:

1. Cars

   - BMW
   - AUDI
   - VW
2. Motorcycles

   - Suzuki
   - BMW
   - Kawasaki

My first page shows a list with

1. Cars
2. Motorcycles

If you click one of the items you ge the nested list. You get the idea.

What I want to do is, that you can click on of the brands in the nested list and get a new page. This page shows, let's say, some details about that brand.
What I dont want to do, is to create seperate html files for each brands, because there will be too many.
So I thought about passing a parameter to a HTML file, which loads, according to that parameter, the details for that brand.

I dont want to use PHP, because in the end I want to use this as a phonegap app.

I'm looking for a simple solution to this, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like one way to do it: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.de/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html

```
// Read a page's GET URL variables and return them as an associative array.
function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

Calling getUrlVars() function would return you the following array:

```
{
    "me"    : "myValue",
    "name2" : "SomeOtherValue"
}
```